# How to change font family of a heatmap created by the pheatmap package

Tags: font-family, pheatmap

I would like to change the font family of the following graph to Times New Roman, 
but couldn't figure out how. Any help will be greatly appreciated! 

A reproducible example:

```
d <- data.frame ( c(runif(5, min=0, max = 5)), c(runif(5, min=0, max = 5)), c(runif(5, min=0, max = 5)), row.names = c("gene1", "gene2", "gene3", "gene4", "gene5"))
colnames(d) <- c("Day 1", "Day 2", "Day3")
pheatmap(d)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `fontfamily` argument to change the font family of the heatmap in `pheatmap`.

`pheatmap(d,fontfamily = "serif")`